# Printing a graph in Fortran77?

Tags: file, graph, plot, fortran, fortran77

I am trying to print a graph in Fortran77 by creating a 2d CHARACTER array. The x value is constant (number of lines in my file) and my y value will be inputted by the user. I initialized all the values to be spaces but I am unsure as to how to fill the 2d array with the points in my file (eg - 1 and 100, 2 and 200) as well as how to prompt the user for a height. Any ideas?

Code:

```
      SUBROUTINE PLOT(L,S)
      INTEGER*8 L
C S = the variable that the user gives for y length, user defined (not sure how to do yet)
      CHARACTER H(L,S)

C
C LOCAL VARIABLES
C
      INTEGER I

      DO 100 I=1, S
        H(I,I) = ' '
100 CONTINUE

      RETURN
      END
```

My data file:

```
1     100
2     200
3     300
4     400
5     500
```

Comment: Do you really need Fortran 77 in year 2014? Anyway do you know how to open a file and how to do basic read from standard input (keyboard) so we have a place where to start?

Comment: I think this is not properly tagged, this is not a plotting issue but a read/write problem. @VladimirF: although new code should probably not be developed in F77, there could be compatibility issues we don't know about such as making some fix to a legacy code.

Comment: why do you want to generate a ASCII plot in 2014?  you can call PGPLOT library and generate nicer plots. Another library is DSLIN. You can install gnuplot and make plots there too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some basic read and write:

To read in a file called `data_in` with `N` lines and variables `x`, `y`, `z` in each line:

```
open(unit=10,file='data_in',status='old')
do i=1,N
  read(10,*) x(i), y(i), z(i)
end do
close(10)
```

To write variables `x`, `y`, `z` of dimension `N` each to a file called `data_out`:

```
open(unit=10,file='data_out',status='unknown')
do i=1,N
  write(10,*) x(i), y(i), z(i)
end do
close(10)
```

To take `x`, `y` and `z` as input from the keyboard (standard input, `*`) asking the user before hand:

```
do i=1,N
  write(*,*) 'Please input element number ', i, ' of variables x, y and z, respectively'
  read(*,*) x(i), y(i), z(i)
end do
```

In each of the three cases, the first option in `read` and `write` is the input/output unit, either referred to with a number (I have used `10` after opening the files with that identifier) of with an asterisk `*`, which signifies "standard input/output", the terminal prompt in this case. The second option, for which I have used an asterisk `*` in all cases refers to the format. `*` is the format "as given".